# Routes Dispatcher example not working in Cherrypy

Tags: python, routes, dispatcher, cherrypy

I tried the Routes Dispatcher example in cherrypy essentials but its not working. its give me `Page not found` error.What am i missing?

```
import cherrypy
class Root:
    def index(self):
        return "Not much to say"
    def hello(self, name):
        return "Hello %s" % name
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Root()
    # Create an instance of the dispatcher
    d = cherrypy.dispatch.RoutesDispatcher()
    # connect a route that will be handled by the 'index' handler
    d.connect('default_route', '', controller=root)
    # connect a route to the 'hello' handler
    # this will match URIs such as '/say/hello/there'
    # but not '/hello/there'
    d.connect('some_other', 'say/:action/:name',
    controller=root, action='hello')
    # set the dispatcher
    conf = {'/': {'request.dispatch': d}}
    cherrypy.quickstart(root, '/', config=conf)
```

Comment: The indentation is broken. If it's the same in your real code, there's your problem.

Comment: i have indented if condition of the above code this is the correct code i have tried. i runned localhost:8080

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try exposing your handlers...

```
 @cherrypy.expose
 def index(self):
    return "Not much to say"
 @cherrypy.expose
 def hello(self, name):
    return "Hello %s" % name
```

Andrew

Comment: Which version of routes are you using?  This guy had problems with version 1.12.1 but was able to get everything working with version  1.10.3.  He was receiving 404 errors the same as you.  https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1010/routes-dispatcher-doesnt-work-with-routes

Comment: Unfortunately that's not correct. Routes are mapped to the handlers explicitly and therefore exposing does not apply to route matching. It's even mentioned by the CherryPy docs.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has long since been solved, but I thought it would be worth noting that I was able to fix routes not working by adding a starting slash to the connected path:

```
d.connect('some_other', 'say/:action/:name',
```

to

```
d.connect('some_other', '/say/:action/:name',
```

Hope this helps someone.